# Django-1.5 DecimalField

Tags: django, decimalformat

I have researched a lot on here and on Google for `DecimalField`. I have the following `models.py`:

```
class Valor(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = ('Valores')

    empresa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, unique=True,
        help_text='Preço do ponto.')

    motoboy = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, unique=True,
        help_text='Valor pago ao motoboy.')
```

If the field is Varchar/max_length the return is:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.empresa
```

How can I return the field when it is a `DecimalField`?

Admin on the values ​​appear as: Valor object

I have another model that contains a

```
Ponto(models.Model):
    valor_empresa = models.ForeignKey('Valor', related_name='valor_empresa', to_field='empresa')
```

In the admin the values appers in the dropdown like this: Valor Object

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    def __str__(self):
    return self.empresa
```

Answer (score 0):

try manually convert decimal object to string like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.empresa
```

If it's not helped, can you specify Django version what you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Yeahh. work in parts

im my model Ponto. The html dropdowns of FK's
   valor_empresa 
   valor_motoboy

brings the same value in both. **to_field** does not work?

My Django is 1.5.9